# Skipping the first row in subsequent worksheets using Java POI that are being copied into a Master file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a merge process in which several workbooks containing multiple worksheets are combined into a Master File.  The sheets are group together by name.

Once the first workbook contents (sheets) are copied, the subsequent (2nd,3rd, 4th, etc) workbook contents (sheets) **should** skip the first row in each sheet and copy to the master file.

- How would I iterate through the subsequent workbook sheets without copying the first row (the headings)?
- Simply put, I want to keep the heading (first row) from the first iteration, then every workbook sheet afterwards that is copied. should skip the first row (heading)

I've included the sample code below.

```
private static void copySheets( XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle) {     
   
        int newRownumber = newSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int maxColumnNum = 0;     
        Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>() : null;    
        
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {     
          XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);     
          XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i + newRownumber); 
          
          if (srcRow != null) {     
              //copyRow(newWorkbook, sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);  
              copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap); 

              if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {     
                  maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();     
              }     
           }     
        }   
                
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {     
          newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));     
        }     
}     

public static void merge(File file) throws IOException {
       XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
       String directoryName = "C: users\\documents";
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file1 : fList){
            if (file1.isFile()){
 String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
                   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);




INTEGRATED CODE

    public static void merge(File file) throws IOException {
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
            System.out.println(file.getName());
           String directoryName = "C:\\ Users\\Documents";
           File directory = new File(directoryName);
           File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            
            Boolean doNotReadHeaders = false;
            Integer fileCount = 0;
            for (File file1 : fList){
                if (file1.isFile()){
                    doNotReadHeaders = (fileCount == 0) ? false : true;
                    String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
    
                 XSSFSheet sheet = b.getSheetAt(0);
                    for (int i = 1; i < (doNotReadHeaders ? sheet2.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1 : sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()); i++) { //Skipping headers only for the first workbook
                        Row row = sheet.getRow(ii);
                        if (row != null) { 
                   
    
                     for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                  XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheet(b.getSheetName(i)); 
                  if (sheet == null) 
                      sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i));
               
                for(int worksheetIndex = 0; worksheetIndex<b.getNumberOfSheets(); worksheetIndex++)
               {    
        
                   b.setSheetName(worksheetIndex, worksheetName);
                System.out.println("test "+ worksheetIndex+ " " + worksheetName);
          
             }
             
               copySheets(sheet, b.getSheetAt(i));
                
                }
            }
            try {
          
            writeFile(book, file);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           } 
          }
```

Comment: public static void merge(File file) throws IOException {
     XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
    String directoryName = "C: users\\documents";
     File directory = new File(directoryName);
     File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
     for (File file1 : fList){
         if (file1.isFile()){
 String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
             FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1 ; i++){
   Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
   if(row != null){
     // process your row
   }
}
```

This way you can skip your heading and can read up to the rows which are not empty!

**EDIT** - If you have a list of workbooks to read, you can manage a check to read headers only for the first workbook, not for remaining workbooks.

```
Boolean doNotReadHeaders = false;
for (int f = 0; f < filesToReadCount; f++) {
    doNotReadHeaders = (f == 0) ? false : true;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); // retrieve input stream acc. to your file lists
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < (doNotReadHeaders ? sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1 : sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()); i++) { //Skipping headers only for the first workbook
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (row != null) {
            // process your row
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** -

```
public static void merge(File file) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        String directoryName = "C: users\\documents";
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        Boolean doNotReadHeaders = false;
        Integer fileCount = 0;
        for (File file1: fList) {
            if (file1.isFile()) {
                doNotReadHeaders = (fileCount == 0) ? false : true;
                String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName + "\\" + ParticularFile));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < (doNotReadHeaders ? sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1 : sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()); i++) { //Skipping headers only for the first workbook
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                    if (row != null) {
                        // process your row
                    }
                }
                fileCount++;
            }
        }
   }
```

I just integrated your code with mine.

**EDIT -** Final Code

```
private static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean doNotReadHeaders, boolean copyStyle) {

        int newRownumber = newSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int maxColumnNum = 0;
        Map< Integer, XSSFCellStyle > styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap< Integer, XSSFCellStyle >() : null;

        int FIRST_ROW_TO_GET = doNotReadHeaders ? 1 : 0;
        for (int ii = FIRST_ROW_TO_GET; ii < sheet.getLastRowNum(); ii++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(ii);
            if (row != null) {
                // The whole row is blank
                //continue;
            } else {
                for (int i = (doNotReadHeaders ? sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1 : sheet.getFirstRowNum()); i < (doNotReadHeaders ? sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() -1 : sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()); i++) {
                    XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);
                    XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i + newRownumber);
                    if (srcRow != null) {
                        //copyRow(newWorkbook, sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);  
                        //copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
                        if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {
                            maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {
            newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));
        }
    }

    public static void merge(File file) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        String directoryName = "C: users\\documents";
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        Boolean doNotReadHeaders = false;
        Integer fileCount = 0;
        for (File file1: fList) {
            if (file1.isFile()) {
                doNotReadHeaders = (fileCount == 0) ? false : true;
                String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName + "\\" + ParticularFile));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); j++) {
                    XSSFSheet innerSheet = workbook.getSheet(workbook.getSheetName(j));
                    if (innerSheet == null)
                        innerSheet = workbook.createSheet(workbook.getSheetName(j));
                    String worksheetName = "Sample sheet ";
                    for (int worksheetIndex = 0; worksheetIndex < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); worksheetIndex++) {
                        workbook.setSheetName(worksheetIndex, worksheetName + worksheetIndex);
                        System.out.println("test " + worksheetIndex + " " + worksheetName);

                    }
                    copySheets(sheet, workbook.getSheetAt(j),doNotReadHeaders,false);
                }
                fileCount++;
            }
            try {
                writeFile(workbook, file1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
```

Now run this and let me know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214102/discussion-on-answer-by-aman-kumayu-skipping-the-first-row-in-subsequent-workshe).